# ConsoleTraceListener(Boolean) - Passing in a string

Tags: c#, xml, tracelistener, tracesource

I set up a TraceListener using this XML:

```
<add name="RuntimeDeploymentConsoleListener"
      type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"
      initializeData="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TraceSourceLogs.log">
</add>
```

I then realised that the `initializeData` attribute is the [string passed to the constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfaf9h0e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the specified class.
However the constructor for `ConsoleTraceListener` takes a `Boolean`. So why does this not throw an Exception at runtime when it tries to convert that string to a Boolean?

Comment: Could you give more details? Are you actually logging something to a trace listener? I get an exception at runtime (ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not create an instance of System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener), but only if I do something that initializes the Trace system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type coercion in web.config is loosy goosy. It probably is looking for either True or False, and not finding the value equal to it, it assumes the opposite.

Most likely it is using Convert.ToBoolean, which will attempt to convert many values without throwing exceptions:

Ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How can we find out what exactly it's doing?

Comment: It's it TraceUtils.cs in the reference source code. It isn't owned by a text writer, so it goes down a different branch. http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/CompMod/System/Diagnostics/TraceUtils@cs/1305376/TraceUtils@cs